# Scripts.Render displaying the bundle name and not the files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently learning MVC, so forgive me if this is an easy one...

I have a BundleConfig.cs file that contains (cut down):

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    // colorbox used in gallery
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/abc").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
              "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

}
```

Notice the bundles/abc ...

In my _Layout.cshtml page, if i write:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

then i get:

```
 <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
```

But, if i write:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/abc")
```

then the NAME of the bundle is rendered in the code:

```
<script src="/bundles/abc"></script>
```

I was expecting to see the following:

```
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

This one has me stumped ... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code to a fresh project and it totally worked for me.

Comment: issue was due to user environment and resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies - After restarting Visual Studio 2015 and also setting the startup project back to the website (I was fiddling with a WCF service), the code is now correctly rendering.

Thanks for your time!